# Fields in Word 2007 shown as code instead of content

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

After some update all my word files now show fields as codes instead of content.

For example where table of contents should be is:

```
{TOC \o "1-2}
```

I can get it to show up by right clicking and selecting activate field, but it reverts to code if the TOC is updated. Activate field is not available in all cases.

Anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value of: Word options -> Advanced -> Show document content -> Show field codes instead of their values? Is it checked?